# Select in the grid a recently added name

Tags: c#

Yesterday I had a few problems but I will explain it better

here is the code

```
private void btnAddNewEmployer_Click(object sender, EventArgs e) {
        //This first code, call a Dialog where the user adds a name a another fields
        using (frmEmployersManager employerManager = new frmEmployersManager()) {
            employerManager.Init(true);
            employerManager.ShowDialog();
        }
        //When they click the Save button, the dialog close, and reloads the grid
        ReloadEmployerData(ctlFilter.Filter);

    }
```

And well, I don't really know how to get the name recently added, get selected in the grid when it reloads again

Any help?

Comment: How to get the name and information that was provided in frmEmployersManager? Add public properties to the form that will return the values of the Textboxes (or whatever other inputs) and assign them to variables before you leave that using block.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Can you create a variable (for example: `var recentlyAddedEmployer= employerManager`) that keeps track of the recently added employer?  Then whenever you add a new name place the employer in the recentlyAddedEmployer